# How do I view all commits on a certain branch in chronological order starting with the OLDEST commit?

Tags: git, github

Preferably, I want to be able to view these commits in a nice way, not using the terminal which is difficult to read (but if that's the only way then that's the only way).

Perhaps it's possible using github, but I could only find the commits sorting from newest to oldest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the standard command-line interface you can use [`git log --reverse <branch>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---reverse):

> `--reverse`
>
> Output the commits chosen to be shown (see Commit Limiting section above) in reverse order. Cannot be combined with `--walk-reflogs`.

`git log` actually takes a "revision range", not necessarily a branch, as an argument. If you want to exclude commits that are also part of another branch, e.g. `master`, you can do something like `git log --reverse master..<branch>`. See [the documentation for `gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for more options.

Unfortunately, `gitk` doesn't accept that argument. I don't know of any way to do this using the GitHub web UI or its desktop client.